# Clone external git repository in release plan

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-2015

We version our deployment configuration/scripts separately to our application, but haven't moved them across to VSTS. I know that Build Plans can pull in external git repositories, but the option doesn't appear to be there for linked artifacts in Release Plans. There also doesn't appear to be a "Clone Git Repository" task.

Any thoughts on what my choices might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should have two options to achieve your requirement:

1. Create a Build Definition and use external git repositories in it, then link the Build Definition in Release Definition:

[image]

2. Although there is no "Clone Git Repository" task, you can use a Command Line task to call `git clone` command:

[image]

Comment: I'd like to avoid #1 as it doesn't allow me to rev the deployment configuration before re-running a release. I guess I'll go with #2, although it will require multiple "Command Line" tasks to pre-cache the credentials, which isn't ideal. Good job for a task group, I guess.

Comment: FWIW, I ended up using #2 with the system accesstoken: `git clone https://oauth:$(SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN)@path/to/_git`

Comment: Same story here. Didn't figure out how to get this SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN though